# Alternatives for self-referential structs in Rust?

Tags: rust

There are tons of questions about self-referential structs in Rust here, and I think I've read them all, but I'm still having trouble wrapping my head around things. What kind of design patterns exist for dealing with self-referential structs in Rust? I'll lay out my thinking so that others can tell me where I'm going wrong (I have a feeling it's at the beginning).

When I'm learning a new language I try to implement the same game, and for Rust I'm running into this problem: we have resources, some of which can be made from other resources. (Let's say they form a DAG.)

My naive attempt to model it is this:

```rust
struct Resource {
  name: String,
  production_cost: HashMap<&Resource, i32>,
  // other data
}
```

We need a lifetime annotation for the reference, so it becomes `Resource<'a>` with a `HashMap<&'a Resource, i32>`.

A `Vec<Resource>` of this form is impractical (impossible?) to build, so another attempt would be to go up a level:

```rust
struct Resource {
  name: String,
  // other data
}

struct ResourceConfig {
  resources: Vec<Resource>,
  resource_costs: HashMap<&Resource, HashMap<&Resource, i32>>,
}
```

I can't figure out a way to construct one of these, either. The next two options I can come up with are:

1. Wrap everything in RefCell/Rc's (or Arc/Mutexes). This seems to require way too much typing, not to mention the reference counting performance overhead (which I'm sure is trivial in my case).
2. Pass around indices to a master vector.

So the end result (2) looks like:

```rust
type RIndex = usize;
type ResourceSet = HashMap<RIndex, i32>;

struct Resource {
  name: String,
  // other data
}

struct ResourceConfig {
  resources: Vec<Resource>,
  resource_costs: HashMap<RIndex, ResourceSet>,
}
```

And the rest of the code just passes around a bunch of `RIndex`'es (and holds on to a `&ResourceConfig` reference to do the conversion). I can upgrade `RIndex` from a type alias to a newtype for type safety at the cost of keystrokes (probably worth it?), but in the end I feel like I'm just doing my own pointer management--instead of worrying about invalid/null pointers I'm worrying about getting a `RIndex` out of range.

What am I missing here? (Unsafe code?)

In C++, I would do something like:

```c++
class Resource {
  std::string name;
  std::unordered_map<Resource*, int> production_cost;
  // Probably wrap the unordered_map in its own class, maybe with a Resource reference, etc.
}
```

(Sure, I'd lose the lifetime guarantees but the resources would all live in the same object somewhere so it wouldn't really be hard to make work.)

Comment: Related (or possibly a duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct

Comment: The problem with a question like this is you're basically asking for software architecture advice, but have abstracted away all the problem-specific details like data dependencies and access patterns which would inform the decision, and architecture doesn't work that way. Sure, any of the approaches you mentioned might be an appropriate way to replace garbage collected pointers in *some* programs, but none of them will be appropriate for *every* program.

Comment: @trentcl is there a better place to ask this question? I guess what I'd like to find is an outline of the different design patterns Rust users use for this kind of situation. StackOverflow is probably not appropriate since you're right, it is more of an architecture question. And as Sven Marnach pointed out there are probably plenty of duplicates here.

Comment: @Peter, you'd be welcome to ask and discuss this in https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/

Comment: Thanks @ArtemGr--looks like [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/e31tan/how_much_different_is_rust_exactly_from_classic/) is a similar question to what I'm after.

Comment: Do you really need `RefCell` when using `Rc`? Do you modify resources inside `production_cost`? It's actually the way to solve such lifetime issues in C++ and in Rust too.

Comment: In C++ you use `*`, not `&`, so what makes you think that in Rust you can get away with using `&`? Their use is pretty much identical. Either use `*mut Resource` if you want to manage that yourself, or use Rc<RefCell<Resource>> which will panic if you mess up. Yeah, wrong access of `*mut` might segfault, but it's not a guarantee.

Comment: @Peter Im learning lifetimes too and Im at a point where Im doing self references and learned that they are wrong and then I stumbled on this post where you said `A Vec<Resource> of this form is impractical (impossible?) to build`. You said that because two `Resource<'a>`s cannot be built at same time and hence they cannot have same lifetime aka `'a`??

Comment: You may want to check out the code from [this DAG crate](https://docs.rs/daggy/0.8.0/daggy/) to see how they did it.

Comment: Pardon my lack of DAG knowledge, but can't a resource own (instead of reference) its sub resources ?

Answer (score 4):

> Pass around indices to a master vector.

You are describing an arena – a vector of structs that can link to each other via indices. There are some [nice crates](https://lib.rs/crates/generational-arena) that let you do this, and provide some compile-time checks.

In your case, we can go one step further – since you don't need to destroy a resource type once it's been created, all of the resources can live for the same lifetime (once created). Therefore, you should in theory be able to have items in the arena reference each other. [typed-arena](https://lib.rs/crates/typed-arena) lets you do just that!

```rust
use typed_arena::Arena;

fn main() {
    let resources = Arena::<Resource>::default();

    let iron = resources.alloc(Resource {
        name: "iron".to_string(),
        cost: vec![],
    });
    let water = resources.alloc(Resource {
        name: "water".to_string(),
        cost: vec![],
    });
    let rust = resources.alloc(Resource {
        name: "rust".to_string(),
        cost: vec![iron, water],
    });

    println!("{iron:?}");
    println!("{water:?}");
    println!("{rust:?}");
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Resource<'a> {
    name: String,
    cost: Vec<&'a Resource<'a>>,
}
```

```
Resource { name: "iron", cost: [] }
Resource { name: "water", cost: [] }
Resource { name: "rust", cost: [Resource { name: "iron", cost: [] }, Resource { name: "water", cost: [] }] }
```